# Python - List of list from txt

Tags: python, list, append

I'm new in programation and I am looking for a way to sort a list of list depending on the first digit of each line in a txt file. In the txt files the number are like this :

0 1

0 2

1 2

1 3

1 0

2 0

2 3

...

And I want to create a list of lists like this : [[1,2], [2,3,0], [0,3,]...] I have try with append and sort but I can't get the answer I want. 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @Vish01 Are the lists within the lists changing in size i.e. 2 numbers (1,2) in list[0], then 3 numbers (2,3,0) in list[1]. then 2 numbers (0,3) in list[2]..... ?

Comment: The number in the txt files are always in pair. But the list can change

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`.

```
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter

with open("your/file/path.txt") as f:
    lines = sorted(f.readlines())

groups = [[int(ss[1:]) for ss in grp] for _, grp in itertools.groupby(lines, itemgetter(0))]
```